# How to delete .dat file in Java?

Tags: java, file

I want to delete a .dat file. This is my code but it does not work.

```
String searchCust = SearchCust.getText();

    File file = new File(searchCust + " booking.dat");
    if (file.delete()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Info deleted");

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete failed");
    }
```

Basically when i run, the file is not deleted and the "Delete failed" message will appear

Comment: Looks like you're not getting the right file. Look if you're passing the right location.

Comment: There is a space between your `searchCust` variable and `booking.dat` once they are concatenated. Is that intentional?

Comment: If you print out the value of `searchCust + " booking.dat"`, what do you have?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(file.exists());` to help debug before you try and delete.

Comment: @Takendarkk yes, the space is intentional because my filename is eg: John booking.dat

Comment: Alright, just covering all the bases.

Comment: @Duncan im getting a 'false'. Why is it so? The file does exist and I am able to read data from it

Comment: @user3532110 You must be making an error somewhere. Try printing out `System.out.println(file)` and see if the path looks correct. If it is a relative path (e.g. `..\John booking.dat`) then ensure you are running from the correct directory.

Answer (score 4):

[`File.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) will return `true` *only* if it deletes the file. Meaning it will return `false` if the file does not exist. Ensure [`File.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) returns `true` prior to invoking `File.delete()`:

```
if (file.exists())
{
    if (file.delete())
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Also see [`Files.deleteIfExists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists%28java.nio.file.Path%29) which may provide more information, via an `IOException`, in the event of a failed deletion attempt:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

try
{
    final Path p = Paths.get(searchCust + " booking.dat");
    if (Files.deleteIfExists(p))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted " + p);
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p + " does not exist.");
    }
}
catch (final IOException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file.exists()){
   boolean isDelete = file.delete();
   if(isDelete){
      //condition
   }else{
     //condition
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good

`fileObject.delete()` is the way to delete the record. But  you should know what is the current working directory in java  first.

Try the below command. Check for its availability : `fileObject.exists()`

`System.getProperty("user.dir");` // fetches the current working directory.

This is the approach, you can fix this problem.